# Upload photo to a custom list using visual webpart in sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net, visual-web-part, image-upload

I have a list, ListPersonalDetails, for storing personal details of students. It has fields like firstName, lastname, address etc. It also contains a field to store the photo which is of type image. I created a visual webpart, StudentPersonalDetails, to add items to ListPersonalDetails. It contains a file upload control used to browse photo. I need to upload the image along with other details to the list. I am using Visual Studio 2010 for my SharePoint site development completely.

used the following code part to update the list:

```
SPListItem studentDetailsItem = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Student Details"].Items.Add();
        studentDetailsItem["StudentID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
        studentDetailsItem["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
        studentDetailsItem["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text; 
        //studentDetailsItem["photo"]=need to upload photo
        studentDetailsItem.Update();
```

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To your Visual Webpart Ascx page, add a File upload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadAttachment" runat="server" />
```

And in your update function, you can upload the attachment by:

```
            SPListItem studentDetailsItem = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Student Details"].Items.Add();
            studentDetailsItem["StudentID"] = Guid.NewGuid();
            studentDetailsItem["FirstName"] = txtFirstName.Text;
            studentDetailsItem["LastName"] = txtLastName.Text; 


            //------------------------------------------------------------
            // If file selected, save to list
            if (FileUploadAttachment.HasFile == true)
            {
                SPAttachmentCollection attach = studentDetailsItem.Attachments;
                String fileName = FileUploadAttachment.PostedFile.FileName;
                byte[] textfile = FileUploadAttachment.FileBytes;
                attach.Add(fileName, textfile);

            }
            // ------------------------------------------------------------

            studentDetailsItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be best to enable attachments on the list and the store the image as an attachment. See [SPAttachmentCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spattachmentcollection.aspx)

Comment: I have file upload control in my visual webpart. I need to upload the file browsed, when i click save button to the field of type 'Image' in a custom list.